# Angularjs: Bind complex objects with selectbox without ng-options

Tags: angularjs

**I need to bind complex objects via a select box.**

**I'm aware of [ng-options](http://jsfiddle.net/pkozlowski_opensource/WdH7x/1/)**, but I cannot use template expression in ng-options. I would need to add field with the displaytext to every object in my controller like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pkozlowski_opensource/WdH7x/1/). That would mean I would need to change logic/code for the presentation. **This is a bad seperation of concerns.**

Is there any way to bind complex objects with a select box **not** using ng-options? I need to write the displaytext declarative in the template like there:

```
<select name="myObject" ng-model="myObject.sub">
    <option ng-selected="!myObject.sub.id"></option>
    <option value="" translate="myObject.sub.self" ng-selected="myObject.sub.id == -1">
    <option ng-repeat="option in subselect.data" value="{{option}}" ng-selected="option.id == myObject.sub.id">
        {{option.id}} {{option.shortName}} {{ option.comment }}
    </option>
</select>
```

currently this is binding the string `[object Object]`, because of the interpolation in the value attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a small helper function with `ng-change` you can capture the index of the selected item to obtain the full object.

HTML

```
<label ng-controller="CompanyController" for="ci-company_sid">
     Company:
     <select ng-model="selectedCompanyIndex" ng-change="update(companysData.companys)">
         <option ng-repeat="c in companysData.companys" value="{{$index}}" ng-selected="c.company.sid == selectedCompany.company.sid">{{c.company.company_name}} - {{c.company.link}}</option>
     </select>
    <hr>
    {{selectedCompany.company.link}}
</label>
```

Controller:

```
function CompanyController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.companysData = {
        "companys": [{
            "company": {
                "link": "\/company\/8256606980000143017",
                "sid": "8256606980000143017",
                "company_name": "Company 29"
            }},
        {
            "company": {
                "link": "\/company\/8256603960000178016",
                "sid": "8256603960000178016",
                "company_name": "Company 1"
            }}]
    }
    $scope.update = function(dataSet){
        $scope.selectedCompany = dataSet[$scope.selectedCompanyIndex];
    }
    $scope.selectedCompany = $scope.companysData.companys[0];
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XzfVZ/3/

Comment: Thanks, this is working and more the way I want this to work. The next step for me is to not have this function in the controller, but creating a reusable directive for that.